# Java Null pointer exception when trying to click on an element that is present in a block and becomes visible when another element is clicked

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-strategy

I'm trying to `click on` an `element`, which is present in a block and the block itself becomes `visible`, when another element `Your Trips` is clicked on.

I'm able to find the element and click on `Your Trips`, but then, when I try to click on the `Sign In` button in the block I'm getting `Null Pointer exception`.

Name of the site: https://www.cleartrip.com/

I want to automate the `sign in` process using `Page object` Model.

[image]

Comment: you are getting Null Pointer Exception, just because may be in your class you would not able to call the driver instance correctly, i would suggest you to check your program logic correctly.

Comment: Also you can paste your code here, so that we can easily check.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Adding a wait for the element to be visible worked.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have to wait for the element to be visible. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium

Comment: Thank you, adding the wait worked.
  public void clickOnToBeginLogin()
  { 

   WebElement element = driver.findElement(SignIn);
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

   driver.findElement(SignIn).click();
   
  }

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)